# Android bytecode verification code

Tags: java, android, bytecode, dalvik

Where can I take a look at android bytecode verificator source, i.e. code which is responsible for throwing java.lang.VerifyError in case of incorrect bytecode? Does verification happens in java or C++ code?

Thanx.

Comment: It may help to read: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/index.html to at least clarify your question further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [art/runtime/verifier](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/verifier/) directory (e.g. [method_verifier.cc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/verifier/method_verifier.cc)), and also [art/runtime/dex_file_verifier.cc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/dex_file_verifier.cc). I think those are the main places where dex/bytecode verification happens, although there may be a few other things sprinkled around.

I'm not sure offhand exactly where the VerifyError exception is thrown, but it is thrown based on the verification performed by the above-mentioned code.